# Invoke WordPress Install without wp-admin/install.php

Tags: php, wordpress, curl

I would like to call WordPress install file without filling out the form on install.php

So I already have the database, username, password, etc.

I tried using cUrl to do this but it seems to just come back blank!

```
$trigger_uri = "https://$cpanel_host/~$cpanel_username/wordpress/wp-admin/install.php?step=2&";

$data_db = "dbname=testforwp&uname=wptestu&pwd=BMkPESD56H1(&dbhost=localhost&prefix=wp_";

$ch_1 = curl_init($trigger_uri);
curl_setopt($ch_1, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_db);
curl_setopt($ch_1, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
curl_setopt($ch_1, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch_1, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch_1, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

$server_output = curl_exec($ch_1);

curl_close($ch_1);

print json_decode( $server_output );
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Easy from command line with WP-CLI. See [wp core install](https://developer.wordpress.org/cli/commands/core/install/) for options.

Comment: @WhereDidMyBrainGo So I have to install WP-CLI on my cPanel first? And then how would I run the wp core install code?

Comment: I don't use cPanel. [Install WP-CLI](http://wp-cli.org/#installing) from command line.

Comment: I'm creating a PHP program where the user clicks a button and it automatically creates them a cPanel account and installs WordPress... So far I have the cPanel account creation working but WordPress install is giving me trouble...